# Using java, how would I read an xml file from a website then put the data from the xml file in a JList?

Tags: java, xml, jlist

Here's the idea of the xml file:

```
<date>
<aug30>
    <item1>This is an item for August 30</item1>
    <item2>This is another item for August 30</item2>
</aug30>
<aug31>
    <item1>This is an item for August 31</item1>
    <item2>This is another item for August 31</item2>
    <item3>This is a 3rd item for August 31</item3>
</aug31>
</date>
```

What I'm trying to figure out how to do is, for example, on August 30, put items 1 and 2 in the aug30 tags into a JList, and on August 31, put items 1, 2 and 3 from the aug31 tags into that same JList.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. This finds only the sections based on the date. I haven't shown the adding to JList, as thats easy. Just change the print statement which prints ADD and you are good to go.

```
    String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
    "<date>\n" +
    "<aug30>\n" +
    "    <item1>This is an item for August 30</item1>\n" +
    "    <item2>This is another item for August 30</item2>\n" +
    "</aug30>\n" +
    "<aug31>\n" +
    "    <item1>This is an item for August 31</item1>\n" +
    "    <item2>This is another item for August 31</item2>\n" +
    "    <item3>This is a 3rd item for August 31</item3>\n" +
    "</aug31>\n" +
    "</date>\n";

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMd");
    String date = df.format(new Date()).toLowerCase();

    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

        DocumentTraversal traversal = (DocumentTraversal) doc;

        NodeIterator iterator = traversal.createNodeIterator(
          doc.getDocumentElement(), NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, true);

        for (Node n = iterator.nextNode(); n != null; n = iterator.nextNode()) {
            String tagname = ((Element) n).getTagName();
            //System.out.println("Compare TAG: '" + tagname + "' with '" + date + "'");
            if(tagname.equals(date)) {
                n = iterator.nextNode();
                tagname = ((Element) n).getTagName();
                while(tagname.startsWith("item") && n != null) {
                    System.out.println("ADD: " + ((Element)n).getTextContent());
                    n = iterator.nextNode();
                    if(n != null) {
                        tagname = ((Element) n).getTagName();
                    } 
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The imports are:

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.traversal.DocumentTraversal;
import org.w3c.dom.traversal.NodeFilter;
import org.w3c.dom.traversal.NodeIterator;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
```

Comment: Well, the JList needs different items everyday, and its not a set number of items. Some days it could have none, while other days it could have 6 items. So the tags aug30 and aug31 would represent the dates August 30, and August 31 and on those days only will it load the items in between the right tag. For example, today is August 31. I only need the items between the aug31 tags to load into the JList.

Comment: Thanks, and what are the imports for this?

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, but i ran the program and it didn't stop adding the elements after it finished adding the aug30 elements. it added the aug31 elements twice. This output I got was

Compare TAG: 'date' with 'aug30'
Compare TAG: 'aug30' with 'aug30'
ADD: This is an item for August 30
ADD: This is another item for August 30
ADD:            This is an item for August 31
              This is another item for August 31
              This is a 3rd item for August 31
         
ADD: This is an item for August 31
ADD: This is another item for August 31
ADD: This is a 3rd item for August 31

Comment: my bad, missed resetting the tagname at the end.

Comment: Please except my answer if you are now happy. Thanks